# Sending object from component to module - Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, components

I'm using CMS Joomla. I created component when I included once library and created object. After that I created module when I need the same object as in component. Can I send object which has been created in component to my module ?

Please help

Comment: Please show some code, it's not really clear what you're asking for. Normally modules can use objects from components if the component is available when the module is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You won't know if your module or component are run first. So your object would need to be created by your own "object factory" in some common include file.